# The extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration

Tags: php, xampp

i am using xampp server with the configuration with the address http://localhost:8080 in windows 8.1 and whenever i try to interact with the database file i mean interact with the database then i get the below error

**The http extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration**

and my config.inc configuration file is this

```
**/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';      
// Authentication method (config, http or cookie based)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'sorry';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'http';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = False;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';**
```

/* User for advanced features */

etc so on

and in here this code is causing error because whatever 
i put in extension
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = '';

for eg. if `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'http';`

then error will be 
A newer version of phpMyAdmin is available and you should consider upgrading. The newest version is 4.4.7, released on 2015-05-16.

A newer version of phpMyAdmin is available and you should consider upgrading. The newest version is 4.4.7, released on 2015-05-16.

The **http** extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. Documentation
i searched in google but i didn't find any problem matchin me.

erroor goes on increasing please someone help me?

Comment: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';` ... it's the php database extension that goes in there not 'http' or anything like that.

Comment: thak you very much from bottom of my heart CDOO1 the problem is solved